# How to get access to IJobexecutionContext in Interrupt method in Quartz.net?

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'm currently developing job manager based on `Quartz.net`. I want to be able to display job execution status in real time so when job interruption request is made I could save `context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Put("status", "interrupting");` in job data map and read this status by fetching all currently executing jobs in scheduler. But, the problem, is I do not have access to `IJobExecutionContext` context object directly in `Interrupt()` method, so I cannot set interrupting status immediately at the moment interruption was requested. This is the functionality I basically want to achieve:

```
class InterruptedException : Exception { }

[PersistJobDataAfterExecution, DisallowConcurrentExecution]
class MyJob : IInterruptableJob
{
    private bool _interrupted;
    private void AssertContinue()
    {
        if (_interrupted) throw new InterruptedException();
    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Put("status", "started");
            AssertContinue();

            // Do the work
            AssertContinue();

            context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Put("status", "completed");
        }
        catch (InterruptedException)
        {
            // Set interrupted status when job is actually interrupted
            context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Put("status", "interrupted");
        }
        catch
        {
            // log any othe errors but set interrupted status only on InterruptedException
        }
    }

    public void Interrupt()
    {
        _interrupted = true;

        // I want to set interrupting statues here!!!
        context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Put("status", "interrupting");
    }
}
```

The basic idea of `IInterruptableJob` interface implementation, as I understand, is to set some `_interrupted` flag value to `true` inside `void Interrupt()` method, then check this flag value on each execution step in `Execute()` method. So, basically, we cannot interrupt the job immediately, we can make interruption request, and only when interruption status check is executed we can interrupt the job by throwing an exception, for example. *But I want to set **interrupting** status for my job during this short period of time. How can I do that? Is it even possible to get `IJobExecutionContext context` object in `Interrupt()` method?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the solution turns out to be pretty obvious and easy. I just have to create private

`IJobExecutionContext _context = null;`

field of my job class and set it's value to `context` in `Execute()` method.

```
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context) 
{
    _context = context;
    ...
}
```

Basically we can interrupt only the executing job so if `Interrupt()` is called than `Execute()` was called at least once so this approach, basically, suits my needs and updates job's `DataMap` immediately after `Interrupt` was called.